# c# Fire an event when Collection capacity is reached or timeout occurs

Tags: c#, collections, thread-safety, observablecollection

I need to execute something when a Collection capacity is reached or timeout occurs.

For example, if i had a list with capacity of 10 and a timeout of 10 seconds will have to wait for one of the "events" raised to execute something.

I was thinking on use a **ObservableCollection** and in the event **CollectionChanged()** count the number of items of the collection and see if is equal to the number max of requests allowed.

At same time i will have a timer to control the timeout.

Can someone please tell me if there is a better solution?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I would use an [AutoResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) on a "watcher" thread. The WaitOne method may timeout or get signaled by the CollectionChanged event (if the capacity is reached).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement you own collection with the features you need.
Something like this:

```
  static void Main()
        {
            var list = new MyObservableCollection<int>(10, 10);

            list.ConditionReachedEvent += () =>
            {
                //Do something
            };

            list.StartTimer();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () =>
                    {
                        // Simulate slow operation
                        Thread.Sleep(12000);
                        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                        {
                            list.Add(i);
                        }
                    });

            Console.Read();
        }

        public sealed class MyObservableCollection<T> : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>
        {
            public event Action ConditionReachedEvent = delegate { };
            private System.Threading.Timer timer;
            private readonly int alertThreshold;
            private long isEventRaised = 0;
            private readonly int timeout = 0;

            public MyObservableCollection(int alertThreshold, int timeout)
            {
                this.alertThreshold = alertThreshold;
                this.timeout = timeout * 1000;
            }

            public void StartTimer()
            {
                Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.isEventRaised, 0);
                this.StopTimer();
                this.timer = new Timer(x =>
                {
                    this.RaiseEvent();
                }, null, this.timeout, this.timeout);
            }

            private void StopTimer()
            {
                if (this.timer != null)
                {
                    this.timer.Dispose();
                    this.timer = null;
                }
            }

            protected override void OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
                if (this.Count >= this.alertThreshold)
                {
                    this.RaiseEvent();
                }
            }

            private void RaiseEvent()
            {
                this.StopTimer();

                if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.isEventRaised, 1, 0) != 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                this.ConditionReachedEvent();
            }
        }
```

With async/await

```
 static void Main()
        {
            var list = new MyObservableCollection<int>(10);
            list.ConditionReachedEvent += () =>
             {

             };

            list.Start(10);

            Task.Run(
                () =>
                {
                    // Simulate slow operation
                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12));
                    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        list.Add(i);
                    }
                });

            Console.Read();
        }


        public sealed class MyObservableCollection<T> : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>
        {
            public event Action ConditionReachedEvent = delegate { };
            private readonly int alertThreshold;
            private readonly TaskCompletionSource<object> capacityReached = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

            public MyObservableCollection(int alertThreshold)
            {
                this.alertThreshold = alertThreshold;
            }

            public async void Start(int timeout)
            {
                var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
                var capacityReachedTask = capacityReached.Task;

                await Task.WhenAny(capacityReachedTask, timeoutTask);
                this.ConditionReachedEvent();
            }

            protected override void OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
                if (this.Count >= this.alertThreshold)
                {
                    capacityReached.TrySetResult(null);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If I were doing this I would use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main"). Then you could do this:

```
var collection = new ObservableCollection<int>();

var query =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<
            NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
            h => collection.CollectionChanged += h, h => collection.CollectionChanged -= h)
        .Select(ep => collection.Count == 10)
        .Where(x => x)
        .Take(1)
        .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0), Observable.Return(false));

query.Subscribe(flag =>
{
    if (flag) // capacity
    {
    }
    else //timeout
    {
    }
});
```

So the `query` effectively watches the `CollectionChanged` event and computes if the count is equal to 10, filters for only when it is 10 (and returns `true`), and takes one value. It then imposes a timeout that returns `false` after 10.0 seconds.